# Loading image inside FXML ImageView?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have the following image in my FXML:

```
        <ImageView>
            <image>
                <Image url="@/Icons/myImage.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
```

My xml file is inside:

```
src/Core/View
```

My icon on the other hand is inside:

```
src/Core/View/Icons
```

Why am I getting the error invalid resource... not found on the classpath? Im not sure what im doing wrong or how to make the path work.

Comment: Omit the leading `/`, i.e. `@Icons/myImage.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change `url="@/Icons/myImage.png"` to `url="@Icons/myImage.png"`, remove the initial `/`